# VLC can't play audio from capture device

Tags: hdmi, alsa, video-capture

I bought HDMI to USB Video Capture and used it on Ubuntu

when i try to play from capture device using VLC the video play with Error regarding audio , after checking the VLC log i found the following:

> alsa error: cannot open ALSA device "default": No such file or
> directory
>
> main error: module not functional
>
> main error: failed to create audio output
>
> access_alsa error: cannot open ALSA device "hw:1,0": No such file or
> directory

lsusb output for the device:

> Bus 003 Device 004: ID 534d:2109

arecord -l :

> **** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
>
> card 1: MS2109 [MS2109], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
>
> Subdevices: 1/1
>
> Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

When i go to settings then sound then input and enable the device i can hear the sound from capture device .

what could be the problem running the audio device through VLC ?

Regards